# C# wpf INotifyChanged does not called when value is same

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 combobox, which include menus name and its details like (Pie-apple, chocolate), (Juice- apple, orange).

So if I select 'Pie' in the first combobox, second one should have its details-apple and chocolate.

Xaml code is below:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
     <TextBlock Text="Menu : " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32"/>
     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LstMenu}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMenu}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32"/>
     <TextBlock Text="Detail: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32"/>
     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LstDetail}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDetail}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" SelectionChanged="combobox_changed"/>
</DockPanel>
```

and viewmodel is below:

```
private List<string> lstMenu;
public List<string> LstMenu {
    get { return lstMenu; }
    set {
      lstMenu = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("LstMenu");
}



private string selectedMenu;
public string SelectedMenu {
    get { return selectedMenu; }
    set {
      selectedMenu= value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedMenu");
      LstDetails = new ObservableCollection<string>( //get its details list from DB );
}


private ObservableCollection<string> lstDetail;
public ObservableCollection<string> LstDetail {
    get { return lstDetail; }
    set {
      lstDetail= value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("LstDetail");

      if (lstDetail != null && lstDetail.Count > 0) {
           SelectedDetail = lstDetail.FirstOrDefault();
      }
}


private string selectedDetail;
public string SelectedDetail {
    get { return selectedDetail; }
    set {
      selectedDetail= value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDetail");
}
```

The problem is, if I selected Pie-apple and then changed the first combobox to Juice menu, Juice-apple is automatically selected but `RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDetail");` does not work.

I know that's because the selected two strings `apple` are same...

However I need to call the event `SelectionChanged="combobox_changed"` since it contains UI reload event.

Moreover, if I added `IsAsync=True` into the LstDetail combobox, it definitely works but `SelectionChanged="combobox_changed"` is called twice. I don't know why.

what should I do?

Comment: It does not trigger because it was not changed. You set the private member variable and not the public property. The event will only be triggered by the setter.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on UI triggering an event and reacting on it itself. Your ViewModel should notify View that it should reload itself.

Comment: As pointed out by @fredrik just replace `selectedDetail` with `SelectedDetail` and it should work.

Comment: @Euphoric The view model shouldn't bother with UI logic. This would be too much details about the view. View model must be view independent. The view must know by itself when to redraw (e.g. data changed).

Comment: @BionicCode And how do you suggest View should know when data changed?

Comment: @Euphoric `Binding` or `DataTrigger`. Maybe I got you wrong, but it sounded like you wanted to let the view model trigger actively some UI action. E.g. when to change background is plain UI logic. View model just exposes data and a notification mechanism to notify about data changes. It doesn't know which changes have to trigger which kind of action in the UI.

Comment: @fredrik Thanks you for your comment, it was my mistake and the event is triggered by the setter, but it still does not work. ```RaisePropertyChanged("selectedDetail")``` is called but ```combobox_changed``` is not called. and I think it is because the detail ```apple``` is not changed. if I changed to another detail like orange, ```combobox_changed``` is called and works properly.

Comment: @W.Cointreau: "Pie-apple" and "Juice-apple"? What is this? Please provide some sample data in your code sample and clarify that your issue is.

Comment: @mm8 I have two comboboxes which are menus and its details. If I select one in menu combobox(pie or juice) the detail combobox shows items which can be selected. So, if I select a pie in menu combobox, apple, chocolate items are binded in detail combobox automatically. The important thing is that the first item in detail combobox is selected at first. The problem is that the first detail item is `apple` whatever I select in menu combobox. So string is same and ```RaisePropertyChanged("selectedDetail")``` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what the architecture of your program is, without a good [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But, from what you've posted, it seems you are trying to do too much of the work, and not letting WPF do its fair share. In particular, you seem to have just one "view model" type, and in that object you attempt to completely define everything that the user sees, and the state of that.

As has been noted in the comments, this has led to a situation where there are pieces of state that relate to each other, but where you haven't done enough work to make sure they stay synchronized with each other. You've delegated *some* of the work to WPF, but it doesn't have enough context to let you know when something important has changed, and so your UI winds up in a inconsistent state.

It would in fact be possible to fix your program as it stands now, by forcing the `SelectedDetail` property to refresh itself if the menu combo box changes. But a) I can't tell you exactly how to do that, because you've omitted *all* of the details that relate to the actual management of that property (such as the `combobox_changed()` event handler), and b) that's really just too much work anyway.

The first thing you need to get on board with, when writing WPF code, is to put as much of your program specification into *declarations*, and not *procedures*. WPF's binding mechanisms do a great job of *automatically* keeping view model data structures in sync with the actual UI. This means that you can view your program as two completely independent entities: the user interface itself, and the "business logic", i.e. the things your program actually has to *do*. The "view model" part mediates between these two elements. In the simplest WPF programs, the business logic itself can be entirely encapsulated in the view model data structures; in more complex applications, the view models focus on mapping between the UI ("view") and the business logic ("model").

This has an important implication: if you find yourself writing code that is directly interacting with the *view* element of your program — i.e. either responding to the UI or modifying it — that code had better be *strictly* specific to the view. Another way to look at that is, such code should be reusable with any other type of business logic, just as all of the built-in XAML stuff is completely reusable and not at all specific to your business logic.

Conversely, if that code you're writing is fiddling with the view model data structures directly or, even worse, is actually *part* of the view model data structures, you've gone off into the weeds. This should *never* happen.

You can use these two metrics to constantly evaluate as you go along whether you're designing the code correctly, and to help guide that design before you actually write the code.

Okay, with that little bit of indoctrination out of the way, here's how *I* would implement your stated goal:

You need some view models. Not just one, because you have a hierarchy of business logic objects, and the view models need to reflect that. Working from the bottom up:

You need a view model that can represent the detail to be displayed. For example:

```cs
class DetailViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _name, value);
    }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _description, value);
    }

    private decimal _price;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get => _price;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _price, value);
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. The above relies on a base class `NotifyPropertyChangedBase` I use for all view models, which provides a convenient mechanism to implement observable properties. Code for that is provided below.
2. The above is strictly a simple data container. For this example, that's all that's needed, because all the example is concerning itself with is how to react to UI input, and WPF is great at managing that already, as long as it has a place to keep everything. A more interesting WPF program would have procedural aspects in the view model for providing commands that operate on the data beyond what the XAML is capable of defining.

Okay, so with a details data structure, we also need a place to keep a list of these objects for each type of menu in your program:

```cs
class MenuViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _name, value);
    }

    private List<DetailViewModel> _menuItems = new List<DetailViewModel>();
    public List<DetailViewModel> MenuItems
    {
        get => _menuItems;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _menuItems, value);
    }

    private DetailViewModel _selectedItem;
    public DetailViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _selectedItem, value);
    }
}
```

You'll note that the above two view model data structures have a `Name` property. This is used to display to the user the name of the item they will be selecting.

The new aspect in this view model is the list of menu item objects, and then a property that keeps track of the *currently selected* menu item object. This is critical with respect to your question: in your implementation, the only thing you know about the currently selected item is its name. But when the same name appears on two different menus, you've got no way to distinguish the two. The only way out of that dilemma, given the design you chose, is to always refresh the details explicitly when the selected menu changes.

But here, we tie the selected item to the menu itself. This gives us two nice results:

1. When the menu changes, then whatever's bound to the selected item property will change as well, implicitly updating the displayed details, because WPF's binding engine understands the relationships of the properties involved. In particular, the details aren't just some random string, but rather a *specific object* that was retrieved from a different *specific object*. If that latter specific object is no longer the context for the binding (i.e. the user picks a new menu), then WPF knows that the former specific object needs to be re-evaluated.
2. By default, the user's selection for a given menu is remembered, because each menu has its own `SelectedItem` property! When the user selects an item from a menu, then selects a different menu, then after they are done with that second menu and go back to the first, the first will still have their previous selection from that menu. Now, this may or may not be the desired behavior. If not, it's reasonably easy in the view model to reset the selected item when the menu changes. But it's usually easier to suppress functionality than to create it, so having the default behavior provide that added functionality is nice.

Finally, of course, we need a place to keep track of the currently selected menu:

```cs
class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private List<MenuViewModel> _menus = new List<MenuViewModel>();
    public List<MenuViewModel> Menus
    {
        get => _menus;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _menus, value);
    }

    private MenuViewModel _selectedMenu;
    public MenuViewModel SelectedMenu
    {
        get => _selectedMenu;
        set => _UpdateField(ref _selectedMenu, value);
    }
}
```

Just like with the menu object, this one has both a list of items (menus, in this case) and a property that keeps track of which specific item is selected.

Now that the view model data structures have been correctly designed to reflect the hierarchy of user selection in our user interface, it's a very simple matter to declare the user interface to work with those data structures:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestSO58167153WpfTwoLevelDetail.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO58167153WpfTwoLevelDetail"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="comboBoxNameTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:DetailViewModel}">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat={}Price: ${0:0.00}}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="100"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenu}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource comboBoxNameTemplate}"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMenu.MenuItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenu.SelectedItem}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource comboBoxNameTemplate}"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      Content="{Binding SelectedMenu.SelectedItem}"/>
  </Grid>

  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:MainViewModel>
      <l:MainViewModel.Menus>
        <l:MenuViewModel Name="Pies">
          <l:MenuViewModel.MenuItems>
            <l:DetailViewModel Name="Apple" Description="Apple Pie with Pastry Crust" Price="10.50"/>
            <l:DetailViewModel Name="Grasshopper" Description="Mint Pie with Oreo Crust" Price="17.95"/>
          </l:MenuViewModel.MenuItems>
        </l:MenuViewModel>
        <l:MenuViewModel Name="Juice">
          <l:MenuViewModel.MenuItems>
            <l:DetailViewModel Name="Apple" Description="Refreshing Apple Juice" Price="3.70"/>
            <l:DetailViewModel Name="Mango" Description="Sweet Mango Juice" Price="4.75"/>
          </l:MenuViewModel.MenuItems>
        </l:MenuViewModel>
      </l:MainViewModel.Menus>
    </l:MainViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

There are two main components to the above:

1. Data templates. These tell WPF how to map the view model data structure to elements in the UI. There are two here: a general-purpose one that just always shows, in a `TextBlock` element, the `Name` property of *any* view model data type; and a template that is specific to the `DetailsViewModel` object, and which displays just the values we're interested in as details.
2. The UI itself. This is super-simple: two `ComboBox` elements, providing the drop-down interface to select both a menu and an item on that menu; one `ContentPresenter`, a control whose main job is just to provide a place to render a data template for a given object; and a `Grid` object to organize it all. The `ComboBox` controls explicitly opt in to the data template that displays the item's `Name` property value, while the `ContentPresenter` infers the correct data template from the type of view model being used (but it also allows the template to be set explicitly, if you so desire).

The only other thing up there is the `DataContext` for the window itself, the content of which I've declared in the XAML here just because it's convenient for the purpose of the sample. In your real-world program, which appears to retrieve data from a database, you'd probably have the top-level view model handle populating itself based on that.

*(Speaking of the data context: in the above, all binding paths are relative to the top-level view model. For the purpose of the sample, this is more convenient, but you of course have complete control over the data context for any element in the UI. An alternative way to implement this would be to set the `DataContext` properties for the controls lower in the dependency hierarchy, so that you don't have to repeat the top-level view model's property names in the binding paths.)*

And that's all there is to it. You can compile and run the above code, and it will do just what you're asking for your code to do.

Minor notes:

1. All of the selections start out blank; you can of course initialize them to non-null values if you want, but doing so in the sample above would just add more code for no useful benefit, at least for the purpose of the sample.)
2. The view models here all use `List<T>` for their collections. This is fine for the example, because these collections never change. But as you likely already know, real-world WPF programs usually use `ObservableCollection<T>`, because generally they are including features that allow for those collections to be modified while the program runs. `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which in turn allows WPF to keep the UI in sync with the bound data. Feel free to replace `List<T>` with `ObservableCollection<T>` here or in any other similar scenario.

As promised, here's the code for the `NotifyPropertyChangedBase` class. There are lots of different ways to implement a base class like this, and in fact I have a different version with a couple more features that I typically use. But this one works well for a basic WPF example (indeed, for many even this one is too "feature-rich" :) ):

```cs
class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```